# Is there a way to automatically insert a numerical sequence into XML file tags using notepad++?

Tags: xml

I need to insert a numeric sequence from 1 to 99 in XML tags using notepad++.

I haven't tried anything yet, I'm new to programming.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to achieve in the Notepad++ by using XSLT.

You would need to install Notepad++ **XML Tools** plugin for that.